How do I render an ASP.NET Core MVC partial view from another project?
I have a large ASP.NET Core MVC web project with many controllers and views. I would also like to make some of my components re-usuable. So I created two separate projects:

Webapp is my web application
Panels is my Razor class library

Panels contains /Views/Shared/_Panel.cshtml. This is a partial that I would like to render.
In my Panels library, I wrote an extension that should allow me to render these correctly:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Html;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Panels.db;
using Panels.Services;

namespace Panels.ProgramExtensions;

public static class HtmlHelperExtensions
{
    public static async Task RenderPanelAsync(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, PanelService service, string panelName)
    {
        Panel? panel = await service.GetPanelAsync(panelName);

        if (panel == null)
        {
            string missingName = $"_PanelMissing";
            await htmlHelper.RenderPartialAsync(missingName, panelName);
            return;
        }

        string foundName = $"_Panel";
        await htmlHelper.RenderPartialAsync(foundName, panel);
    }

    public static async Task<IHtmlContent> PanelAsync(this IHtmlHelper htmlHelper, PanelService service, string panelName)
    {
        Panel? panel = await service.GetPanelAsync(panelName);

        if (panel == null)
        {
            string missingName = $"_PanelMissing";
            return await htmlHelper.PartialAsync(missingName, panelName);
        }

        string foundName = $"_Panel";
        return await htmlHelper.PartialAsync(foundName, panel);
    }
}

And then call it like this in my web app project:
//Some code
<div class="justify-content-center">
    @await Html.PanelAsync(panelService, "Navbar Core");
</div>
//Some more code

However, when I try this, I get this error:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
InvalidOperationException: The partial view '_PanelMissing' was not found. The following locations were searched:
/Views/Home/_PanelMissing.cshtml
/Views/Shared/_PanelMissing.cshtml
/Pages/Shared/_PanelMissing.cshtml

To resolve this, I have tried

Adding the views to the WebHostEnvironment
Using a ViewLocationExpander (the one in the code I will attach is broken because of the ../)
Using absolute file paths in the HtmlHelper extensions
Mapping two sets of endpoints

None of those options have worked. It is likely that I just didn't do one of them right. How can I make this work?
Here is some code:
ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs:
using System.Reflection;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders;
using Panels.db;

namespace Panels.ProgramExtensions;

public static class ApplicationBuilderExtensions
{
    public static IApplicationBuilder UsePanels(this IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        // Setup views
        var env = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IWebHostEnvironment>();
        var embeddedFileProvider = new EmbeddedFileProvider(typeof(Services.PanelService).GetTypeInfo().Assembly);
        env.ContentRootFileProvider = new CompositeFileProvider(env.ContentRootFileProvider, embeddedFileProvider);

        // Ensure database is created
        using (var serviceScope = app.ApplicationServices.GetRequiredService<IServiceScopeFactory>().CreateScope())
        {
            var context = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<PanelsContext>();
            context.Database.EnsureCreated();

            try
            {
                _ = context.Panels.FirstOrDefault();
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                // Table doesn't exist yet.
                RelationalDatabaseCreator databaseCreator = (RelationalDatabaseCreator)context.Database.GetService<IDatabaseCreator>();
                databaseCreator.CreateTables();
            }
        }

        // Configure the routes for the Panels project
        app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
        {
            endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "Panels",
                pattern: "Panels/{controller=Panel}/{action=Index}/{id?}",
                defaults: new { area = "Panels" },
                constraints: new { area = "Panels" });
        });

        return app;
    }
}

ServiceCollectionExtensions.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Razor;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Panels.Controllers;
using Panels.db;
using Panels.Services;

namespace Panels.ProgramExtensions;

public static class ServiceCollectionExtensions
{
    public static IServiceCollection AddPanels(this IServiceCollection services, string connectionString)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<PanelsContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
        services.AddScoped<PanelService>();
        services.AddControllersWithViews()
            .AddApplicationPart(typeof(PanelController).Assembly)
            .AddRazorRuntimeCompilation();
        return services;
    }
}

public class PanelViewLocationExpander : IViewLocationExpander
{
    public void PopulateValues(ViewLocationExpanderContext context) { }

    public IEnumerable<string> ExpandViewLocations(ViewLocationExpanderContext context, IEnumerable<string> viewLocations)
    {
        viewLocations = new[] { "~/../Webapp-Panel/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" }
            .Union(viewLocations);
        return viewLocations;
    }
}


Hi @JD9999, what if you change <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor"> to <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web"> in project file?

@Rena I get the error "error CS5001: Program does not contain a static 'Main' method suitable for an entry point". I guess because I don't have a Program.cs?
I don't want this to be a standalone web application (unless it has to be), I more want this to be a library.
